# Is there a command pallette for visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I basically want to know if there's an equivalent `command+shift+p` that's in visual studio code, but for "visual studio 2015" or the later.

There seems to be a thread about it right [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a048992-49e3-41cb-b117-a2b6e9f43d13/how-to-open-command-palette-in-vs2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

But still couldn't find an alternative.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL-Q?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I think that's a valid asnwer. Il asnwer up the question

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found was to use the `Quick Launch` which corresponds to `CTRL-Q`.
I really never saw it, when it was right in front of me.